# Compare two datetime fields in power bi query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have column name as IsGreater.
This column is filled by comparing two fields of dates.
one is today's date and another is date field in text format ex: "12/1/2018 8:00:00 AM" in text format.
I need to compare these two dates and return true or false.

Thanks in advance.

I am trying

```
IsGreater = IF((FORMAT(TODAY(),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt"))> 
(FORMAT([date],"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt")),true,false)
and
IsGreater = IF((FORMAT(TODAY(),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt"))> 
(FORMAT([date],"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt")),True(),False())
```

It's not working as assumed.
Need in help.

expected to be true as the date field contains "**12/1/2018 8:00:00 AM**" which is past.

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder DD and MM:

```
= IF((FORMAT(TODAY(),"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt"))> 
(FORMAT([Date],"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt")),true,false)
```

Comment: It wont work, as the [Date] format is like 12/27/2018 8:00:00 PM ie., MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt format

Comment: Now I get it. You compare text values. So just transform them to dates:

=DATEVALUE(FORMAT(TODAY(),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"))> 
DATEVALUE(FORMAT([date],"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"))